# Extract AD group members

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've AD groups, for example: ABC1, ABC2, ABC3 etc..

is there a way I can extract members of all groups starting with "ABC" into following excel format

| Group Name | Member |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1 | Member1 |

I started with this, but unable to get further

```
 Get-ADGroupMember -identity "ABC1" | select name  Export-CSV -Path ".\Groupmembers.csv
```

Comment: What format whould the `Member` column have? DN of the member? ObjectGUID? SamAccountName? SID?

Comment: Just the name field

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the `.Name` attribute of the objects, you can do this using `Get-ADObject` to filter all those groups which's `samAccountName` starts with `ABC` then for each group search for all those AD objects being a `memberOf` of that group:

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(samAccountName=ABC*)' | ForEach-Object {
    $members = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ('(memberof={0})' -f $_.DistinguishedName)
    foreach($member in $members) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            GroupName   = $_.Name
            Member      = $member.Name
            ObjectClass = $member.ObjectClass
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```